# What's a proper way to export a global constant from a module?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

Declaring global constants might be convenient, but is not easy in C++. E.g. see [this recent article at Fluent C++](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2019/07/23/how-to-define-a-global-constant-in-cpp/). It mostly explains how to do it, but does not mention C++20 modules.

In a regular header file on a namespace level I would declare a constant like this:

```
// Constants.h
inline constexpr int Count = 42;
inline const std::vector<int> Numbers = { 1, 2, 3 };  // cannot use constexpr
```

Here I need `inline`, since the symbols might be included in several translation units. IIUC, a module definition unit exporting a symbol is a separate translation unit. So I would declare it simply as following:

```
// Constants.ixx
export module constants;

export constexpr int Count = 42;
export const std::vector<int> Numbers = { 1, 2, 3 };  // cannot use constexpr
```

Is this the proper thing to do, or am I missing something?

Comment: Why don't you export getter instead? This way code using these constants will be decoupled from the implementation of storage of those variables. And I should mention that the linked article is somewhat misleading. It mixes all the `inline` `static` `extern` and creates a total mess while all these variants can be helpful in different scenarios.

Comment: @VTT The question is more about understanding how modules work, from the point of view of this particular example. However, I see nothing bad in exporting a scalar (`Count` in my case) as a variable, without a getter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did it right.  Note also the important feature that, like `inline` in C++17, dependencies expressed via `import` [constrain initialization order](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2019/p1874r0.html) (with or without `inline`) in C++20.

Comment: What would be the point of exporting something from a module with `inline`? I thought it just was not applicable to modules.

Comment: @Mikhail: `inline` does apply to *functions* in modules: the plan is for it to [impose certain useful restrictions](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2019/p1498r1.html) to improve optimization.  It doesn’t do anything useful for variables, and I didn’t say that it did.

Comment: @Mikhail: Upon further reflection, it’s still meaningful (as a convenience) to define static data members as `inline` in a module; it means there is no separate definition in another module unit.